# Are there tools to analyse large Java heap dumps without loading the complete hprof file?

Tags: java, profiling, heap-memory

I use Eclipse MAT to analyse hprof files. It is very good but if you have a 2Gb heap dump then you need to run MAT with a 2Gb+ heap size itself to be able to load the complete heap dump.

I was wondering if anyone knows of a tool that could analyse a 2Gb hprof file without using that much memory itself (e.g. it doesn't load the complete file but somehow walks through it)? This would be useful if a hprof file gets generated on a customer server as I could then run some analysis on the server instead of trying to copy a 2Gb file over a VPN.

Comment: I doubt that this is possible, but I'll be curious to see if it is.

Comment: So do I but thought this would be the place to ask.

Comment: I have only evaluated JProfiler and YourKit and have to say that the latter is doing so much better than the former when the memory is sparse. YMMV, of course. Never tried Eclipse MAT though.

Comment: I know it's a terrible answer, but that's what comments are for. ;-) It might actually be faster to copy the 2-gig file over a VPN than to spend all of the time and effort required to find and learn a tool to do this for you. It depends a lot on just how many times you expect to do this; if it's less than five or six, you're probably better off copying the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hprof files have a format that doesn't really work well without loading it fully and then applying some cross-referencing afterwards.

However, you may be able to skip the hprof dump to get just basic information from the running VM by using `jmap`, `jstack`, and `visualvm` included in the JDK package.
Typical memory leaks for example should be visible from the jmap heap histogram already, as you might be able to guess the places that produce or retain objects just by looking at the number of instances of a particular class.

Answer (score 2):

The latest versions of YourKit handle large heap dumps much better than before.  I've had good success with it and highly recommend it.  A long time ago there was a tool called Auptyma by Virag Saksena, but it appears that it may have been bought by Oracle.